# How to control individual form element rendering in Zend Form?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

**Brief**

I am using `Zend Form` library.  I want to be able to style or have some control over how radio boxes are constructed.  Currently the rendering of the element is "in one row".  What I want to do however is render each option on its own line.  Library does not seem to provide an easy injection of i.e. `<br>` tag, which is what I would normally use in my HTML.  I need help figuring out how to bend the library to my needs anyway.

**Controller**

```
    use Zend\Form\Element;
    use Zend\Form\Form;

    $radio = new Element\Radio('gender');

    $radio->setValueOptions(array(
        '1' => 'Male',
        '2' => 'Female',
        '3' => 'Other',            
    ));
    $radio->setValue(2);
```

**In View**

```
<?=$this->formRadio($this->form->get('gender'));?>
```

**Observe Element Rendered as**

```
* Male * Female * Other
```

**Want Element rendered as**

```
* Male
* Female
* Other
```

How?

**Sample HTML Rendering**

```
<form class='my-form'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label><input name="gender" type="radio" value="1">Male</label> 
                <label><input name="gender" type="radio" value="2">Female</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can side-step Zend Framework completely and save some page-weight (by not using `br` tags) by using CSS to solve this problem.

Simply look at the tag or classname of the repeated element being used to render your list items (sounds like it's a radio input) and style it to display vertically instead of horizontally.

An example:

```
.my-form input[type="radio"] {
    display: block;
}
```

This will be faster and simpler than custom rendering decorators in Zend.

EDIT: Now that you have provided the exact HTML, here is some refinement.

1) The inputs are nested within the labels, so you will modify the display of the labels instead of the inputs.

```
.my-form label {
    display: block;
}
```

2) The rendered form (if this is exact) does not currently have a class name. If the form will never be used more than once on a page than the current ID is fine and you will have to change the selector in the CSS to use ID notation.

`#myform label` instead of `.my-form label`

Otherwise, you can use Zend's `setAttribute` function to add a class name like so.

`$form -> setAttribute('class', 'my-form');`

Comment: I did this and the element rendered as radio box for "male" on line 1, radio value on the 2nd line, then radio box for "female" on line 3 and so on.  I would like to keep radio box and value on the same line

Comment: If you paste the rendered HTML I can show you the styles the fix that.

Comment: gah.. well it works but it sets every element's label in the form to show as "block".  I am trying to do this only for the single element, the specific radio box.  So far failing my CSS.  Tried Zend's `$element->setLabelAttributes()` method but it does not seem to work for me - namely I expected it to insert a `style` into the label element itself but it does nothing

Comment: Yeah just change the css selector to be more specific. I'll see if I can remember how to add classes to form elements in Zend after lunch.

Comment: I got the Zend Part yay `$element->setLabelAttributes(array('style' => 'display:block'));`  I was using `,` instead of `=>`.  So this is now working for me.

Comment: Nice. Glad you got it.